# Append a row N times into Pandas DF combining apply and append

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm receiving the following error:

```
  File "/packages/pandas/core/common.py", line 380, in _asarray_tuplesafe
    result[:] = [tuple(x) for x in values]
TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not iterable
```

When running:

```
df.apply(lambda row: (df2.append(([row]*(row[6].split(',').__len__())), ignore_index=True)), axis=1)
```

The goal is to apply for each origin dataframe row (`df`) an append N times to an empty df (`df2`). Where N is the number of values that the specific field `row[6]` has.

Rows of example are for the `df`:

**Id**|**List**

---

0|126

---

1|126,127,304,305

---

The `df2` should be:

**Id**|**List**

---

0|126

---

1|126

---

1|127

---

1|304

---

1|305

---

As you can see I tried sending the row as a list, but don't work neither. Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way after `split` using [`unnesting`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe/53218939#53218939)

```
df.List=df.List.str.split(',')
unnesting(df,['List'])
Out[466]: 
  List  Id
0  126   0
1  126   1
1  127   1
1  304   1
1  305   1
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```